# Facebook user still logged in after logging out

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I'm integrating Facebook into my application.  A user in my app can either be authenticated via Facebook, or be authenticated by their account (email address + password) with the app.  I have a page in my app where I pull Facebook friends list using FB Javascript sdk.  I log into the app using Facebook authentication then navigate to the page and can see my friends list.  I can then logout of app using FB.logout then login to the app using a different user account (email + password) then navigate to the page and still see my friends list.  I've logged into the app using a non-facebook authenticated login.  It's not a caching issue as I have no caching set up in my dev environment.  I'm new to Facebook.  Any ideas on why the friends page is still retrieving friends list?  Thank you!

Comment: Are you storing the user token in a session?

If you are, are you destroying the session on logout ?

Comment: thanks for your input.  I'm not intentionally setting the user token coming back from calling FB.login().  (I think it's login, I'm writing this from memory).  Is the javascript FB sdk setting the token itself?  Maybe the browser is caching this?

Comment: Most probably you are not handling user sessions properly. Somewhere you are messing with detecting which user is logged in!

Comment: the only user "session" i have is storing the user key in local storage for the browser.  That should not have any bearing on my app retrieving friends list when I navigate to the friends list after logging out of Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the browser is caching the friend list, unless your loading the friends list after the page is loaded via ajax. But even then it would be rare to see such a thing.

I've never used the js sdk. But i know with the PHP one it automatically stores the fb token in the session. However ive just had a thought, if your using the JS SDK, that probably means that your not using tokens like the PHP sdk does. I would guess that its because facebook is detecting the user as logged in ?

Try logging out of facebook after you logout of your own site, then login with a different account. If that works, then you need to google around and get the code for logging them out of facebook. I believe the old trick was to just header redirect them to the facebook logout url, but there may be a nicer way of doing this.

Having said that, this would log them out of facebook, so you might annoy some people. How often can you see people logging out to log in with a different account?

Comment: i'm experiencing this just messing around in my dev environment logging in/out as different users.  The facebook friends list is consistently being returned from the same facebook login account regardless of who I log in as.  so, in reality a user would not login/out as I'm doing.  It's bugging me in a development environment that I'm consistently getting facebook friends list for someone other than the currently logged in user.  Thanks for your feedback.